# Play 2 Json format, capture Int or String

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a problem, I use an rest webservice than return an json not well formatted, sometimes return a string sometimes an integer in the same field. This is the code of the format:

```
implicit val ItemFormat: Format[Item] = (
  (JsPath \ "a").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "b").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "c").formatNullable[String]
  )(Item.apply , unlift(Item.unapply))
```

If c is empty or not exist or is a string works well, but if the c is an integer I have this error:
ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))

I would obtain, if c is an integer, or convert it in a string or put c=None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
case class Item(a: String, b: String, c: Option[String])

implicit val reads: Reads[A] = new Reads[A] { 
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A] = { 
    for {
      a <- (json \ "a").validate[String]
      b <- (json \ "b").validate[String]
    } yield {
      val cValue = (json \ "c")
      val cOptString = cValue.asOpt[String].orElse(cValue.asOpt[Int].map(_.toString))
      Item(a, b, cOptString)
    }
  }
}
```